# foreach with modulo operator outputs on weird places

Tags: php, magento, modulo

I have this code:

```
<?php $manufactors = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('hersteller_logos')->toHtml(); ?>
<?php $manufactors = str_replace("<br />", "|", nl2br($manufactors)); ?>
<?php $manufactors = str_replace("<img", "<img class=\"img-responsive\"", $manufactors); ?>
<?php $manufactors = str_replace(array("\n", "\r"), '', $manufactors); ?>
<?php $manufactors = str_replace(" |", "|", $manufactors); ?>
<?php $_manufactors = explode("|", $manufactors); ?>

<?php $manuSize = count($_manufactors); ?>
<?php if($manuSize > 0): ?>
<section class="hidden-xs">
    <div id="manufactors-featured" class="carousel slide panel panel-default" style="min-height: 300px;">
        <div class="carousel-inner">
            <?php $_columnCount = 4; ?>
            <?php $x = 0; ?>
            <?php foreach($_manufactors as $item): ?>
                    <?php if($x++%$_columnCount==0): ?>
                        <div class="item <?php if($x-1 == 0): echo 'active'; endif; ?>">
                            <div class="row">
                    <?php endif; ?>
                            <div class="col-md-3">
                                <?php echo $item; ?>
                            </div>
                    <?php if($x%$_columnCount === 0 || $x === $_collectionSize): ?>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    <?php endif; ?>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </div>          
            <a class="left carousel-control" href="#manufactors-featured" data-slide="prev"><span class="icon-prev"></span></a>
            <a class="right carousel-control" href="#manufactors-featured" data-slide="next"><span class="icon-next"></span></a>
    </div>
</section>
<?php endif; ?>
```

The requested string contains the following:

```
<p><img src="{{media url="wysiwyg/350px.png"}}" alt="" /></p>
<p><img src="{{media url="wysiwyg/350px.png"}}" alt="" /></p>
<p><img src="{{media url="wysiwyg/350px.png"}}" alt="" /></p>
<p><img src="{{media url="wysiwyg/350px.png"}}" alt="" /></p>
<p><img src="{{media url="wysiwyg/350px.png"}}" alt="" /></p>
<p><img src="{{media url="wysiwyg/350px.png"}}" alt="" /></p>
<p><img src="{{media url="wysiwyg/350px.png"}}" alt="" /></p>
<p><img src="{{media url="wysiwyg/350px.png"}}" alt="" /></p>
<p><img src="{{media url="wysiwyg/350px.png"}}" alt="" /></p>
<p><img src="{{media url="wysiwyg/350px.png"}}" alt="" /></p>
<p><img src="{{media url="wysiwyg/350px.png"}}" alt="" /></p>
<p><img src="{{media url="wysiwyg/350px.png"}}" alt="" /></p>
<p><img src="{{media url="wysiwyg/350px.png"}}" alt="" /></p>
<p><img src="{{media url="wysiwyg/350px.png"}}" alt="" /></p>
<p><img src="{{media url="wysiwyg/350px.png"}}" alt="" /></p>
<p><img src="{{media url="wysiwyg/350px.png"}}" alt="" /></p>
<p><img src="{{media url="wysiwyg/350px.png"}}" alt="" /></p>
<p><img src="{{media url="wysiwyg/350px.png"}}" alt="" /></p>
<p><img src="{{media url="wysiwyg/350px.png"}}" alt="" /></p>
<p><img src="{{media url="wysiwyg/350px.png"}}" alt="" /></p>
<p><img src="{{media url="wysiwyg/350px.png"}}" alt="" /></p>
<p><img src="{{media url="wysiwyg/350px.png"}}" alt="" /></p>
<p><img src="{{media url="wysiwyg/350px.png"}}" alt="" /></p>
<p><img src="{{media url="wysiwyg/350px.png"}}" alt="" /></p>
<p><img src="{{media url="wysiwyg/350px.png"}}" alt="" /></p>
<p><img src="{{media url="wysiwyg/350px.png"}}" alt="" /></p>
<p><img src="{{media url="wysiwyg/350px.png"}}" alt="" /></p>
<p><img src="{{media url="wysiwyg/350px.png"}}" alt="" /></p>
<p><img src="{{media url="wysiwyg/350px.png"}}" alt="" /></p>
<p><img src="{{media url="wysiwyg/350px.png"}}" alt="" /></p>
```

I expect a output that fits each 4 of those lines into a div.item > div.row - but the very first div.item > div.row only contains ONE col-md-3, the other 3 are dropped below the div.item > div.row element.

Output is the following:

```
<section class="hidden-xs">
        <div id="manufactors-featured" class="carousel slide panel panel-default" style="min-height: 300px;">
            <div class="carousel-inner">
                <div class="item active">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-3">
                            <p><img class="img-responsive" src="localhost/media/wysiwyg/350px.png" alt=""></p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <p><img class="img-responsive" src="localhost/media/wysiwyg/350px.png" alt=""></p>
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <p><img class="img-responsive" src="localhost/media/wysiwyg/350px.png" alt=""></p>
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <p><img class="img-responsive" src="localhost/media/wysiwyg/350px.png" alt=""></p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="item ">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <p><img class="img-responsive" src="localhost/media/wysiwyg/350px.png" alt=""></p>
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <p><img class="img-responsive" src="localhost/media/wysiwyg/350px.png" alt=""></p>
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <p><img class="img-responsive" src="localhost/media/wysiwyg/350px.png" alt=""></p>
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <p><img class="img-responsive" src="localhost/media/wysiwyg/350px.png" alt=""></p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

...
```

What the hell am I doing wrong? Here is a screenshot of the output in the frontend:

[image]

Comment: `<?php if((($x++)%($_columnCount))==0): ?>`  and `<?php if((($x)%($_columnCount)) === 0 || $x === $_collectionSize): ?>`

Comment: @Anant: tried, output is still the very same (hasn't worked). Further, why should one put brackets around each variables? Whats the meaning of this? Thanks!